# How can i represent 3D space using 4x4 matrix?

Tags: matrices, 3d

I want to represent 3D space using 4x4 matrix as we represent 2D plane using following form.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        cos\theta & sin\theta & 0 \\
        -sin\theta &cos\theta &  0 \\
        x & y & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

can 3D space be presented in 4x4 matrix?

how can i apply operations like rotation,translation and transformation to the object using this transformation matrix?

Comment: See for example [here](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~hegde/cad/lecture/L6_3dtrans.pdf) for the direct generalization.

Comment: What do you mean by represent? In what sense?

Comment: @mathreadler i mean to represent them in matrix format. in accordance with 2D representation. using which we can multiply standard matrix directly to that presented matrix to do transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices of the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&c&0\\
b&d&0\\
u&v&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
does not represent the $2D$-plane, but **affine transformations** in the  $2D$-plane when the points of this space are represented by means of [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) $P=(x,y,1)$.

In this case the product 
$$
(x,y,1)
\begin{bmatrix}
a&c&0\\
b&d&0\\
u&v&1
\end{bmatrix}= (ax+by+u,cx+dy+v,1)
$$
represents the combination of a linear transformation (given by the $2\times 2$ matrice with the terms $a,b,c,d$) and a translation given by $x,y$.

We can extend the use of homogeneous coordinates to any space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in the case $n=3$ the points can be represented by a quadruple $P= (x,y,z,1)$ and a matrix of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&d&g&0\\
b&e&h&0\\
c&f&k&0\\
u&v&w&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
represents, in the same manner, a combination of a translation given by the vector $(u,v,w)$ and a linear transformation given by the $3\times 3$ matrices with the other entries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. it's really useful.